# Angular DataTables - ajax call from local storage

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I'm looking for a way to make an ajax call to local storage which already has a json object stored so it can be loaded into the table.

```
loadDataTable() {
  this.jsonService.getJson().subscribe(response => {
    this.dataToRead = response.data;
  });

  this.dtOptions = {
    ajax: this.dataToRead,
    columns: [{
     title: 'ID',
     data: 'id'
    },
    {
     title: 'Name',
     data: 'name'
    },
    {
     title: 'Age',
     data: 'age',
    },
    {
     title: 'Address',
     data: 'address'
    }],
    rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
      const self = this;
      $('td', row).unbind('click');
      $('td', row).bind('click', () => {
      self.viewFarmDetails(data);
      });
      return row;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in the local storage you can read it.

Import any utility library in your component (ngx-webstorage, for example)

```
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';
```

Add it to your constructor

```
constructor(private $localStorage: LocalStorageService) {
}
```

Then read from localStorage, whenever you need to

```
this.$localStorage.retrieve('my-data-in-storage')
```

replace 'my-data-in-storage' with your key in the storage for that data!

Hope this will help!